# Disable rotation for item in tabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBarController which has 4 items. One of them is a camera (a barcode scanner) which I implemented with AVCaptureSession. So, if you tab the tab "scanner" will automatically show you a camera screen.

The problem is that I can't disable autorotate of individual items of the tabBarController. So, the screen of the camera rotates when you rotate the device and is very weird.

I tried:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return false

}
```

and

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return .Portrait

}
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppDelegate add the following

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Then go to each view and add the following in `viewWillAppear`

```
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
// false = only portrait
// true = all orientations
appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
```

**Update**
To lock the screen when you go from landscape to portrait, just add this code in viewWillAppear.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, but the problem now is if you have the device in landscape and tap the tab "scanner screen", when it appears is in landscape and you have to move to portrait.

Comment: Now there is a problem with bounds of the device which I didn't have before (when go from landscape to portrait the heigh of the camera screen is smaller). I added `self.previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;` to viewWillAppear but it doesn't work. Maybe a better and quick solution would be let the screen rotate (the tab bar, time etc) but don't let the camera rotate.

Comment: Sure try that and if it´s not sufficient for you, we´ll find another solution :)

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how to implement that xD. I was searching it before post but I didn't find any solution. The idea is leave the camera image always in portrait orientation and the rest of the objects rotate with the screen. Maybe it could be a bit tricky.